# Thread-safe multi-values map

Tags: java, spring, thread-safety, guava, multimap

need store multiple values with specific key. I decide to use Guava's cache class for that, which contains another functions, e.g auto-remove entries after some time and so on ...

I implement this "multimap" like this:

```
private final Cache<String, HashSet<NotificationType>> notifications = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
```

I need some List or Set associated with each key where my threads will be stores notification types for user's key.

Can you tell me if my usage is thread-safe solution, and if isn't, can you  advice me some another good solution which is? I am using Spring as main framework if it helps you to give me better answer. Thanks in advice!

Comment: You probably want to use `asMap().compute` when modifying the set, to ensure (a) modifications are thread-safe, (b) the entry is not evicted while modifying. This method is a bit buggy and slow in Guava, so you might consider Caffeine instead. If the set is read by multiple threads, you might either use `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` or `ImmutableSet`.